# Encontro Developers Conference (TDC) São Paulo

Tags: debate

Com a indicação do @Math, descobri o evento [TDC](http://www.thedevelopersconference.com.br/tdc/2015/index.html#saopaulo) que acontecerá de 21 a 25 julho, vou participar no dia 25(Sábado) da trilha Java, alguém mais se inscreveu?

Seria interessante para fazer um networking entre os "Stackers" do SOpt.

[Trilhas disponíveis](http://www.thedevelopersconference.com.br/tdc/2015/saopaulo/trilhas)

Comment: Que vontade de participar. Pena que SP é bem longe. kkkk

Comment: Não tem em MG né?

Comment: Estarei na trilha de .NET dia 25 :D

Comment: Show! @LetticiaNicoli, vi que já esgotou .net.

Comment: Acabou pra .NET. Só vou dia 7 pra cerveja.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez, trilha Java, HAHAHA

Comment: @WellingtonAvelino Prefiro ficar **dormindo em casa** que ir ver isso aí.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez, hahaha